# Jquery loading animation, destroy on pageload

Tags: jquery, loading, pageload

I am trying something, which I don't know if it works that way. I am triggering a loading animation with JQuery onclick, which looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").hide();
});

$(".spin").click(function() {
    $('#spinner').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

So every time a button with the class "spin" is clicked, a loader with the id "spinner" is faded in.

I just want to do that, because loading times are sometimes pretty long, and without loading indication for the user, it will look like the page stopped working for several seconds.

So far so "good", that works, as the "spinner" is set to display: none; by css, when the new page is loaded. I also use a document ready function on the #spinner to hide(); it on pageload.

But when I hit the **page-back-button** in the browser (**Firefox, not Chrome**), I come back to the last page where the spinner is still spinning infinite.

Is there any way to destroy the click function I triggered before, shortly before the new page is loaded, so the back button can be used?

Is there a better way to achieve that, withou ajax?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just add fade-out on document ready

Answer (score 0):

Just add `fade-out` on the script tag on the page after the #spinner html

```
       $('#spinner').fadeOut();
```

or use document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly hide it with JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").hide();
});
```

---

Rather than hiding the spinner only with JS, hide it with CSS by default as well.

CSS

```
#spinner{display: none;}
```

JS

```
$(".spin").click(function() {
    $('#spinner').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: Yeah. I've done that before, and it works perfectly fine with Chrome. Nevertheless, Firefox doesn't accept this and the spinner is still there after a page-back click :(

Comment: haha thanks! but I do that as well :) must be any stupid mistake i make here :)